# Swift: centering a label with another control in the way

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I'm wondering if I can move a label to the center of a view even if there are other hidden controls in the way. I'm using Swift 1.2 and I'm using auto-layout for the initial position.

So I really have two questions:

1. How can I move a label to the center? I've found plenty of examples of moving to a particular location based on the original position. I just want the center. I tried this:

   ```
    self.labelTest.center = self.view.center
   ```
2. Will it work 'over' hidden controls or do I have to move them too? i.e., to get them out of the way
   Thanks

Comment: As you are using autoLayout, so try to set the constraints of the label rather than setting the frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.labelTest.center = self.view.center
```

This instruction won't be affected by the existence of any other views on your self.view if autolayout is off. However if autolayout is enabled depending on what constraints you've set they may interfere with the positioning of your views. So either turn off AutoLayout or ensure the constraints don't hinder your view being centered.

Comment: Thanks. "ensure the constraints don't hinder your view being centered." How would I do this? The constraints have the other controls in the way, so how could i still use them and get the label centered?

Comment: You need to add a constraint to the view that keeps it centered. You can add the constraint programmatically or through storyboard. This stack overflow question examines making two views have the same centre using autolayout. [Centering a UIView using Autolayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496341/how-can-i-center-a-uiview-programmatically-on-top-of-an-existing-uiview-using-au)