# Autolayout programmatically with UILabel doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

So I want to center horizontal and vertical a UILabel in my View programmatically. I follow [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496341/how-can-i-center-a-uiview-programmatically-on-top-of-an-existing-uiview-using-au) but it doesn't work. How can I do that?

p/s: this is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let noDataLabel = UILabel()
        noDataLabel.text = "No data :("
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        noDataLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
        noDataLabel.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(noDataLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
 noDataLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

From apple documentation:

> By default, the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to
>   constraints that fully determine 
>        the view's position. This allows the auto layout system to track the frames of views whose 
>        layout is controlled manually (through -setFrame:, for example).
>        When you elect to position the view using auto layout by adding your own constraints, 
>        you must set this property to NO. IB will do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You also need create size constraints for `uilabel` like below and add it to your superView

```
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
 NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
```

your implementation will look like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let noDataLabel = UILabel()
        noDataLabel.text = "No data :("
        noDataLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        noDataLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
        noDataLabel.sizeToFit()

        noDataLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(noDataLabel)

        let horizontal = NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
        let vertical = NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
        let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: noDataLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)

        self.view.addConstraint(horizontal)
        self.view.addConstraint(vertical)
        self.view.addConstraint(width)
        self.view.addConstraint(height)
    }
}
```